# windows AD server has been corrupted

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have used windows 2008 AD since 2013.and I have secondary domain as well. unfortunate due to hardware failure the primary domain was corrupted. I configured a new AD on windows 2012R2.now my concern is when I restart my primary domain it giving many errors. "Naming information cannot be located because: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. Contact your system administrator to verify that your domain is properly configured and is currently online."

It will automatically  resolving when I switch on the secondary domain.

Now what I want to do , I need to resolve this error..

Answer (score 0):

Which server holds the FSMO roles? Are both servers Global Catalog and DNS servers?

What is the status of Sysvol.Go to Registry editor and open the key SysvolReady at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I resolved this problem changing the vale of SysvolReady 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a known issue.

These issues may occur if TCP/IP filtering is configured to permit only port 80 for TCP/IP traffic.

And you can consult the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/cannot-start-active-directory-users-and-computers-tool#resolution) for a possible solution